# is it possible to forge the amount of memory available on a VPS?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, memory-usage, memory-leak

I have a VPS with directadmin installed on.
The amount of memory I bought from my VPS provider is 1GB and in the system it it shows that I have 1GB of memory available.
From the beginning I regularly checked the memory usage of the system, and it never came below 600MB. I thought it's ok until recently. I suspect something must be wrong, because my memory usage now is above 850MB.

I used the `top` and `ps aux` commands and got the list of running processes on the system. after doing the math I got that the memory usage of apache and mysql summed up should not be much above 500MB.
I then did something else: I deactivated the apache and mysql and again saw that the used memory is stuck around 600MB.

What I want to know here is, am I doing it wrong (calculating memory)? Or is my provider lying about the amount of memory they gave me? Is it even possible, or there's a hidden process eating up the system memory?

Comment: Checked memory usage using what command?

Comment: @Paul `free -t -m`

Comment: Please read http://linuxatemyram.com  If that doesn't answer your question, please post the output of the free command here.

Comment: I'm pretty confident you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @SvenW  well that's a relief! I would've picked your answer as the best if it wasn't a comment! ;)

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have earned *Confused by Linux memory usage* badge!

Processes are not the only thing eating up memory in Linux. The frequently used files and directory entries are cached in RAM - that's because reading the files from RAM is lots faster than reading them from disk. I bet you didn't take *buffers* and *cached* columns into account while calculating the RAM usage. Those can be calculated as free RAM, too.

But don't you worry. Those *caches* and *buffers* automatically get flushed in no time if your applications actually need that RAM.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably being confused by memory caching, see http://www.linuxatemyram.com/.

There is a python script available at http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ps_mem.py that will give you a slightly more accurate view of global and per-app memory usage.